# How to remove previous Windows version?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

Due to the recent upgrade of Windows 10, I am now almost out of disk space on my system drive. I received a "Notification" from Windows advising me to remove the previous version to save space, but it also told me that I would not be able to go back once I did that. I clicked on the notification, expecting something to happen, but nothing did. The notification just went away. Does anyone know how to find or remove the previous version? All I get when I search this site is related to upgrading to Windows 10 from Windows 8.

Comment: There is typically a Windows.old folder on your root C drive. This contains all the information Windows wants in case you decide to go back to your previous operating system.

Comment: Use Disk Clean-up and select Clean-up systems files to remove previous versions.

Comment: Did you upgrade from previous build of Windows 10 to a newer build of Windows 10? *This is the way I understood the question, and I edited accordingly.*

Comment: Yes Sammy. That is what happened.
Since posting my question, the notification popped up again and this time I was sure to choose the option to remove the old version. I picked up about a 1G of disk space so I assume all is well now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\ look for Windows.old if it is not there then you have removed the previous version of Windows.

If it's still there delete it by using the "Windows Disk Cleanup" tool. 
On Windows 10

- Click start.
- Search for Disk Cleanup
- Select the areas you'd like to cleanup

Comment: In addition to my comment above, I also searched for windows.old and came up empty handed. Thank you John.

Comment: Did you do the search before or after choosing to remove the old version when you were prompted the second time? If you searched after that, then it's normal that you didn't find anything.